# Why is the JS engine giving "undefined" for console.log(parent.firstElementChild)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-devtools

[The Chrome Developer Tools CORRECTLY IDENTIFIES the first and lastElementChild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZsnr.png)

The following is the portion of the HTML in which I am facing the problem. The following is the JS code which I want to understand/rectify:
:

```js
let parent = document.getElementsByClassName("parent");
console.log(parent);
console.log(parent.firstElementChild);
parent.firstElementChild.style.color = "green";
parent.lastElementChild.style.color = "green";
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="firstChild">
    <h1>This is the 1st child</h1>
  </div>
  <a class="secondChild" href="https:\\www.google.com"> This is the 2nd child</a>
  <br>
  <p class="lastChild"> This is the 3rd child</p>
</div>
```

I wanted to make the 1st and the last child as Green color. But, `console.log(parent.firstElementChild)` is undefined, even though the engine recognizes the firstElementChild and the lastElementChild. So I am not able to change the color. Can anyone please shed some light over this?

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns a collection so you'll need to get the 1st item of it.